# CSS / JavaScript files not changing in adminhtml (cache?)

Tags: adminhtml, javascript, cache, css, block-cache

I have an unusual issue occurring in the admin panel, I updated M2ePro and it has a new set of css/js files that need to be changed to make it work. The problem is when I change this in my phtml file, nothing changes. Here's a list of things I've tried:

- Disabled Full Page Cache via XML (and refreshed config cache to make sure that changes in app/etc/modules reflected)
- Clear Cache and Cache Storage, as well as manually rm -rf var/cache/*
- Refreshing all types of cache
- Disabled Javascript merging to see what files were moved/missing exactly
- Ran a script to manually refresh all types of cache regardless of a tag (the Magento way)

Mind you, this installation uses the standard Magento cache methods, the only difference is we have allocated memory mounted at var/cache so it runs faster, as we had numerous issues with Memcache and had to use this method instead, which still works fine with all the normal Magento methods of cache implementation. My permissions are correct, `chown`'d and `chmod`'d to 755 across the board.

Am I missing anything here? This has had me stumped for a couple of days now which is longer than this sort of issue should ever take.

Any advice or questions to help solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I searched through all the files to find any other instances of addJS(), turns out I was editing the wrong file for the specific page I wanted.